# python checking if one list can equal another (in value and order) if elements in one are deleted

Tags: arrays, list, python-2.7

I have two lists of input (call one a, the other b), I am trying to see if a can be matched to b if elements of a are removed.  For example if a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4] and b = [1,2,3] , the function would find that it can remove one occurrence of 1, two occurrences of 3 and the only occurrence of 4 so that a == b.  I don't know how I would go about getting this to work in Python.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2, 3]

i = 0
ans = False
if len(a) >= len(b):
    for item in a:
        if item == b[i]:
            i += 1
            if i >= len(b):
                ans = True
                break

print ans
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as efficient as sophiadw's answer, but this approach will tell you which items in `a` aren't needed to match `b`, and the input lists don't need to be sorted.

```
from collections import Counter

#returns False if a can't be pared down to match b.
#If it can be pared down, returns a dictionary of which items to remove.
def can_match(a,b):
    c_a = Counter(a)
    c_b = Counter(b)    
    if c_b - c_a:
        return False
    return c_a - c_b

a = [1,1,2,3,3,3,4]
b = [1,2,3]
print can_match(a,b)
```

Result:

```
Counter({3: 2, 1: 1, 4: 1})
```